# Connecting smartdiagrams' sequence diagrams

Tags: nodes, arrows, tikz-arrows, smartdiagram

I'm completely new at TikZ and Smartdiagrams, and can't find any help to make the following diagram: [image: Diagram drawing]

Each of those items is a sequence diagram of only one item (they have to be sequence diagrams to match the style of previous diagrams, otherwise I would have to emulate the style of smartdiagram's sequence items manually). My problem is that in order to draw those arrows, all of these mini-sequence diagrams would need to be within a tikzpicture environment, but that is not possible.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. In particular, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pure TikZ (is `smartdiagram` enough smart for this?):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,
               border=3mm,
               ]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning,
                shapes.symbols,
                }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 2mm and 5mm,
sgn/.style = {signal, draw, signal from=west,
              minimum height=1.2em, minimum width=3em},
                        ]
\node (n1) [sgn]  {$x$};
\coordinate[below right=of n1]  (a);
\node (n2) [sgn,below left=of a]  {$y$};
%
\node (n3) [sgn,right=7mm of a]  {$z$};
\coordinate[right=of n3]  (b);
\node (n4) [sgn,above right=of b]  {$a$};
\node (n5) [sgn,below right=of b]  {$b$};
%
\draw[gray,thick]  
    (n1) -| (a) |- (n2)
    (n3) -- (b);
\draw[-Straight Barb]  
    (a) -- (n3.north west |- n3.west);
\draw[Straight Barb-Straight Barb]
    (n4.north west |- n4.west) -| (b) |- (n5.north west |- n5.west);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

*Note*: in future please consider *CarLaTeX* comment, now you lucky to obtain answer (since you are novice).

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! Also I think I can learn a couple of things of TikZ from your answer! :) What is CarLaTeX?

Comment: @Truncarlos, *CarLaTeX is who in (s)he is member of this site and author of comment below your question.